# Why does // have lower precedence than equality in perl?

Tags: perl

Why does `//` have lower precedence than `==` in (at least) perl 5.010?

For example, this

```
use 5.010;
my $may_be_undefined = 1;
my $is_equal_to_two = ($may_be_undefined//0 == 2);
say $is_equal_to_two;
```

prints (for me) *very* unexpected result.

Comment: Because Larry Wall designed it that way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because of the category of operators which `//` falls under, aswell as `==`.

`==` is an "*equality operator*" though `//` falls under the category of "*C-style logical operators*".

As an example; `&&` is in the same "*category*" as `//`, with that said both of the statements below are equivalent when it comes to operator precedence. That might make it easier to understand?

```
  print "hello world" if $may_be_undefined && 0 == 2;
  print "hello world" if $may_be_undefined // 0 == 2;
```

---

**[Documentation of C-style Logical Defined-Or ( // )](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Defined-Or)**

> **Although it has no direct equivalent in C, Perl's // operator is related to its C-style or. In fact, it's exactly the same as ||, except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its truth.**
>
> Thus, $a // $b is similar to defined($a) || $b (except that it returns the value of $a rather than the value of defined($a)) and yields the same result as defined($a) ? $a : $b (except that the ternary-operator form can be used as a lvalue, while $a // $b cannot).
>
> This is very useful for providing default values for variables. If you actually want to test if at least one of $a and $b is defined, use defined($a // $b) .
>
> The ||, // and && operators return the last value evaluated (unlike C's || and &&, which return 0 or 1).

---

[Documentation of Operator Precedence and Associativity](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity)

Comment: OK, but why is // in this category? &&, || etc. are logical operators. I don't see // as a C-style logical operator.

Comment: @KarelBílek I modified my post and added relevant info and links to the perl documentation regarding the matter, the text explains it quite well.

Comment: @Karel, `3 || 4` return `3` not `1` in Perl, i.e. `//` does operate like a *Perl* logical operator.  Yes, `0//1` returns `0` but that's fine.

Comment: @JeffBurdges:oh, OK. I was still thinking about C's **logical** operators and it didn't add up. But yes, perl's || trully works like this. All right. It still seems to me that // would be far more useful with higher precedence, but OK, Larry designed it that way.

Comment: Larry Wall (or whoever added it to Perl) does see it as a logical operator - so you had better adjust your expectations to match the language you are using (or decide not to use the operator).

Comment: From perlop, about a language design decision made back in 1989: "Operators borrows from C keep the same precedence relationship with each other, even where C's precedence is slightly screwy. (This makes learning Perl easier for C folks.)"