# What does '//' mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, logical-operators

I was searching in a lot of Perl books but I can't find an answer. I have this code, what I suppose it does is assign param's ticket to $ticket iff it exists if not, assign 0.

```
my $ticket   = $params->{ticket} // 0;
```

Comment: Good hit. google `man perlop` and search for `//` on that page.

Comment: Apologies for the erroneous answer. I made a mistake.

Comment: The "defined-or" operator was added to Perl in version 5.10 which was released in December 2007. So any books that you have which are more than five years old won't mention it for obvious reasons :)

Comment: Duplicates [Meaning of // operator in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12911365). Related: [What is //= in perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13846676) [Why does // have lower precedence than equality in perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8469273)

Answer (score 9):

`//` means [defined-or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or). `$ticket` is assigned `$params->{ticket}` if it is defined, 0 otherwise.

> Although it has no direct equivalent in C, Perl's `//` operator is related to its C-style or. In fact, it's exactly the same as `||`, except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its truth. Thus, `EXPR1 // EXPR2` returns the value of `EXPR1` if it's defined, otherwise, the value of `EXPR2` is returned.

It was [added in 5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/perldelta.html#Defined-or-operator).

In the code above, `$params->{ticket}` can still have garbage in it, so make sure the value conforms to the expected pattern before using it.

Answer (score 4):

Perl [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) says:

"EXPR1 // EXPR2 returns the value of EXPR1 if it's defined, otherwise, the value of EXPR2 is returned."

It's similar to a logic or, but testing definedness.